# Problem running second instance of Tomcat on the same machine

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to run a second instance of Tomcat on the same machine of a previous instance.
Steps:
1) I copied all the files and folder of the first instance so now I have

```
/opt/tomcat1
/opt/tomcat2
```

2) I modified all the ports in server.xml (the first instance run on 8080, 8443, etc, the seconds run on 9090, 9443, etc)

While the first instance is already running, I try to set the CATALINA_HOME to /opt/tomcat2 in the following ways

1) in setenv.sh

```
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat2"
export CATALINA_BASE="/opt/tomcat2"
```

2) in startup.sh

```
export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat2"
export CATALINA_BASE="/opt/tomcat2"
```

3) in external script

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx800m -Xms800m"
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat2
CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat2

 export JAVA_HOME JAVA_OPTS CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE

 echo $CATALINA_HOME

 $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
```

None of these work, Tomcat starts but died immediately with only this log

```
27-Mar-2019 11:18:35.984 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.036 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9443"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.087 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9009"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.138 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.147 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.149 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9443"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.150 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9009"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.171 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.173 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-9443"]
27-Mar-2019 11:18:36.173 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9009"]
```

I am pretty sure that:

- it is not a problem of conflicting port
- it is not a problem of memory

Even if I stopped the first instance, the second instance stops immediately.

I followed also this guide (https://www.c2b2.co.uk/middleware-blog/how-to-create-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-the-same-server.php) , but still same error ; the second Tomcat instance starts and suddenly dies.

Any hints?

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I found the (very stupid) problem: in server.xml the shutdown port had a NON valid value (-2) . I changed to 7005 and all is ok.

```
<Server port="-2"
```